# CodeIgniter - simple error, missing brackets somewhere

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a simple function and have ran in to that oh-too-common error. I have tried removing different brackets and adding and cannot get the error to go away.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /application/controllers/users.php on line 246

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $user = $this->model_auth->check_credentials($this->session->all_userdata()['logged_data']['email']);
    if (!empty($user))
    {
        $this->Model_Users->delete($id);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('ses_user_deleted', '<div class="alert alert-success fade in" role="alert"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">

        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><strong>User have deleted successfully</strong></div>');

        redirect('users/index');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->set_data();
        $this->load->view('header_view', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('unauthorised_view');
    }
    else {
        redirect('Welcome');
    }
}
```

Comment: `if` - `elseif` - `else`

Answer (score 1):

You need to open if statement, or change "else" to "if", because now you have two else's but no ifs.

[image]

Comment: Maybe because it is late but I am not following you. I already have an opening bracket? Could you please explain.

Comment: If-else statement must start with "if" and then follow with "else", now you have only "else" part ;) http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: Your code probably must look like something like this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d5336b3dea23f0c814ae0b272842627fe3bc8c62

Comment: Got it, stupid mistake, thank you all. Now I will hide my head in the sand:)

Comment: Accept the answer if it is useful to you (click the green tick underneath the upvote downvote bit next to the answer.) this will improve S.O.